# Polynomials of Continuous Bijective Functions Dense in C([a,b])

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question that I cam across while practicing some old comprehensive exams at my school and I was wondering if you could offer some advice towards working through it. The question is as follows

Let $f(x):[a,b]\to[a,b]$ be a continuous, one-to-one, onto function. Show that $\{p(f(x)):p(x)\text{ is a polynomial}\}$ is dense in $C([a,b])$.

While thinking about it, I noticed a few things but I don't know how helpful they will be.

1. $f^{-1}$ is one-to-one, onto, and uniformly continuous.
2. $f([a,b])=[a,b]$ or $[b,a]$.

What I did was choose an arbitrary function $g(x)\in C([a,b])$. Then considered the function $h(x)=g(f^{-1}(x))$, which is clearly in $C([a,b])$. Then I know that I can approximate $h(x)$, by the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, using some some polynomial $\mathcal{P}_h(x)$, depending on $\epsilon$. So that I get
\begin{align*}
||h(x)-\mathcal{P}_h(x)||_\infty<\epsilon
\end{align*}
Implying
\begin{align*}
||h(f(x))-\mathcal{P}_h(f(x))||_\infty&=||g(x)-\mathcal{P}_h(f(x))||_\infty<\epsilon
\end{align*}
Is this all that this problem boils down to? Or is there more to it than this?

Comment: This works, but if you're going to use Weierstrass approximation, I think you can just show that your set separates points directly and then Stone-Weierstrass says it is dense.  Also, I think it takes a little work to show $f^{-1}$ is continuous, but it's true.